# Deleting an item from my collectionview doesn't work in real time xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have an Sqlite Database, when i delete something, for the changes to take place i need to restart my emulator (Looks like they don't refresh automatically.)

This is probably due to ObservableCollection but i am new and there's something i am doing wrong.

Saving an item to my agenda works . But Saving an agenda is on an other page (maybe that's why it refreshes). But even tho it works im unsure if it's the good way to do, i am just adding an agenda to my database in seems like but i don't have any reference on a collection.

Thank you for your help.

I'll include the most i can to give you an idea :

**My BaseViewModel in the ViewModel folder**

```
namespace Calculette.ViewModel
{
    // Classe qui implemente INotifyPropertyChanged. Notify clients that a property value has changed.
    public class BaseViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        protected void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        // Création des propriétés d'un agenda

        private string topic;
        public string Topic
        {
            get => topic;
            set
            {
                topic = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        private string duration;
        public string Duration
        {
            get => duration;
            set
            {
                duration = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        private DateTime date;
        public DateTime Date
        {
            get => date;
            set
            {
                date = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        bool isBusy = false;
        public bool IsBusy
        {
            get { return isBusy; }
            set
            {
                isBusy = value;

                NotifyPropertyChanged();

                //AgendaSaveFormCommand.ChangeCanExecute();
            }
        }

        public int ID { get; }
```

**AgendaPageViewModel ( the page that displays all my agendas)**

```
    public class AgendaPageViewModel:BaseViewModel
    {
 public ObservableCollection<Agenda> Agendas { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<Agenda>();
public Command DeleteAgendaCommand { get; set; }

        public AgendaPageViewModel()
        {

            DeleteAgendaCommand = new Command(new Action<object>((obj) =>
            {
                DeleteAgenda((Agenda)obj);
            }));
        }
        private void DeleteAgenda(Agenda selectedItem)
        {

            App.Database.DeleteAgendaAsync(selectedItem);
            Agendas.Remove(selectedItem);
        }
```

**My delete icon on AgendaPage.xaml**

```
<ImageButton Source="iconmoins.png" HeightRequest="30" WidthRequest="30" Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference AgendaCollection}, Path=BindingContext.DeleteAgendaCommand}"CommandParameter="{Binding .}"></ImageButton>
```

**My delete function in AgendaDatabase.cs in the Database folder**

```
public Task<int> DeleteAgendaAsync(Agenda agenda)
{
    return database.DeleteAsync(agenda);
}
```

**This is how i save my agendas to my mainpage in NewFormViewModel.cs to give you an idea**

```
class NewFormViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {

        public Command AgendaSaveFormCommand { get; set; }


        public NewFormViewModel()
        {
            // Initialise la valeur du DatePicker a celle d'aujourd'hui
            this.Date = DateTime.Now;

            // Commande pour la sauvegarde sur la page NewFormPage ( voir SaveForm() plus bas)
            AgendaSaveFormCommand = new Command(async () => await SaveForm(), () => !IsBusy);
            
        }


*/
        // Methode qui enregistre un agenda et l'ajoute a la collection d'agenda de AgendaPage
        async Task SaveForm()
        {
            
         IsBusy = true;
         await Task.Delay(4000);

            
           IsBusy = false;
            Agenda agenda = new Agenda();

            agenda.Topic = Topic;
            agenda.Date = Date;
            agenda.Duration = Duration;
            //AgendaCollection.Add(agenda);
            await App.Database.SaveAgendaAsync(agenda);
           
            await Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Save", "La tâche a été enregistrée", "OK");
            await Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PopAsync();
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
```

**How i load my data in my main page in the AgendaPage.xaml.cs**

```
  protected override async void OnAppearing()
   {
   base.OnAppearing();
   AgendaCollection.ItemsSource = await App.Database.GetAgendasAsync();
   }
```

Comment: `Agendas.Remove(selectedItem);` - where is `Agendas` defined?

Comment: Oops just added it in : AgendaPageViewModel  at the start, but it seems to me that this is empty for some reason or isn't linked with the Database, im not sure haha.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is setting the `ItemsSource` directly to a db result, it will never get refreshed

```
AgendaCollection.ItemsSource = await App.Database.GetAgendasAsync();
```

instead, use your VM

```
var data = await App.Database.GetAgendasAsync();
vm.Agendas = new ObservableCollection(data);
AgendaCollection.ItemsSource = vm.Agendas;
```

Comment: var vm = this.BindingContext as AgendaPageViewModel;
            vm.Agendas = await App.Database.GetAgendasAsync();
            AgendaCollection.ItemsSource = vm.Agendas; ok i did this but for second line, it says impossible to implicitly convert system.collections.generic.list to system.collections.objectmodel.observableCollection how do i fix this ? thanks !